# Open url/file when clicking bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with twitter's bootstrap accordion. I need it to where when i click the accordion title, the title opens up something i href it to.

```
<div class="container">
<p class="max-width-700 lead">testing</p>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-sm-30"> 
 <div class="accordion">
 <div class="accordion-title">
<a href="">2014 (Opening)</a>
 </div>

 <div class="accordion-title">
  <a href="">2015 </a>
 </div>
 <div class="accordion-content">
</div>
```

[Something like this, so when i click 2014, it opens up a document or file i have linked it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmxju.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open file inside the accordion tab or need open file only like open pdf file an other window ?

In bootstrap you can't open link until you remove its according function

Comment: I need to open a file/pdf in a new tab when you click on it

Comment: your requirement seems you don't need accordion you just need style of it and open the link :) so go with list group style from bootstrap component link - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group

Answer (score 0):

(1)
Use a `boostrap-collapse.js` event.  See http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Give each title a unique id and then add the following js to the end of your HTML.

```
$('#myItem1').on('show', function () {
  window.location.href = '1.0.pdf';
})
```

(2)
The accordion is specifically designed to open an underlying hidden content.  Using it to open external files is not expected behaviour - I would strongly recommend not using this type of UX - some users will see this as clickbait.

(3)
The `.accordion` class comes from Boostrap 2(?)  2 is no longer supported.